# Is there any path magic to specify an external drive in Windows from relative path?

Tags: windows, path

Without using slashes (`/`) or backslashes (`\`), is there any way I can create a file on an external drive using a relative path on windows?

Or, put less confusingly...
Say I have to append whatever I do to the path:

```
C:\Application Data\blib\
```

Is there any way I can do something like:

```
C:\Application Data\blib\<WINDOWS_SORCERY>external:\wherever\file.txt
```

I've tried inserting delete characters (`\x7f`) and backspace characters (`\x08`), and the reserved characters, but nothing doing. And from what I can tell the reserved characters would only be helpful if the file were being created from within a batch script; it's being created in a Java program.

edit: By 'nothing doing' I mean I get an error message; the program doesn't strip those characters out.

Comment: The program strips out slashes and normal relative path stuff. So, putting `example/../../../../../test` doesn't work.

Comment: If you stepped on the path of hacker, go ahead and patch the executable.

Comment: @Vadzim It's actually not as blackhat as it sounds. Just making my job slightly easier. And yes, if I find a vuln I'll disclose to the vendor. I also know this question is a bit of a shot in the dark, but I'm mainly a nix guy.

Comment: @Vadzim Additionally, props for the 'stepped on the path' turn of phrase. Intentional or not, it made me smile.